# Webview html audio player in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

[image]

How to get this audio player in webview,if we play a audio link in chrome or any browser,
it gives something like above by default,Can we get exactly like in android webview.
I tried to get html elements,but UI was looking very odd-

Attempt 1-

```
var iframeURL = string.Format("<video width=\"{0}\" height=\"{1}\" controls=\"\" autoplay=\"\" name=\"media\"><source src=\"{2}\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></video>",
            width, height, embedUrl);
        string finalUrl = string.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", iframeURL);
```

and this final url is my web source

Attempt 2-

```
var iframeURL = string.Format("<iframe style=\"position:fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%;" +
      " width:" + " {1}px; height: {2}px; margin-left: {3}px; margin-top: {4}px;\"" + " src =\"{0}\" frameborder=\"0\" " + "allow=\"accelerometer;" +
      " autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
            embedUrl, width, height, -width / 2, -height / 2);
        string finalUrl = string.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", iframeURL);
        return finalUrl;
```

Comment: Are you working on Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android project?

Comment: working on xamarin.forms....but anything will work i guess...i can do custom renederer but problem is what should be proper html

Comment: Why don't you use audio element?

Comment: tried,not working,it just shows a play image,nothing else

Comment: Is my answer work for you?

Comment: @S.TuğçeArar,Yes it worked ,Thanks a lot...Just wondering how to change background color,sorry i am not good in html things

Comment: Page's background or audioplayer's?

Comment: never mind ..i got it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be do it,

```
   var html = string.Format("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\"
   content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"></head><body><audio controls
   autoplay name=\"media\"><source src=\"{0}\" type=\"audio/mpeg\"></audio> 
   </body></html>",embedUrl);
    webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
    Html = html,
    };
```

XAML:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></WebView>
```

Result:

[image: ture]